# Response.Redirect() sem gerar System.Threading.ThreadAbortException?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Em todos os pontos do sistema que tem um `Response.Redirect("/Url.aspx");`

Gera a exception do tipo `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException`, mas funciona.

Tem algum jeito de fazer o Response.Redirect, sem gerar a exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este é um problema específico do WebForms e não ocorre no ASP.NET MVC, por isso adicionei a tag correcta à pergunta.

Traduzido [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2777204/857807):

O padrão é chamar o overload de `Redirect` com o parametro `endResponse=false` e dizer ao IIS para completar a request imediatamente assim que o método terminar.

```
Response.Redirect(url, endResponse: false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

[Este blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx) do Thomas Marquardt explica este problema e também como fazer um *redirect* dentro dum handler `Application_Error`.